# Handle form submission with Vert.X

Tags: html, forms, vert.x

I have a very simple form submission page for testing purpose

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:8080/queries" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" id="includeOtherPMs"/> include other PMs
        <input type="checkbox" id="includePreCanned"/> include pre-canned
        <input type="search" id="keyword">
        <input type="submit" id="listQueries" value="filter"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I have a Vert.x HTTP server to handle the request:

```
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
router.route("/queries").handler(new QueriesHandler());
vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router).listen(8080);
```

But in the QueriesHandler, I tries request header, form attributes, query parameters from both "get" and "post" method of the form submission, but none of them could get any value.

```
public class QueriesHandler implements Handler<RoutingContext> {
    @Override
    public void handle(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        MultiMap headers = routingContext.request().headers();
        MultiMap params = routingContext.request().formAttributes();
        MultiMap qp = routingContext.queryParams();
    }
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is my fault. I should use "name" rather than "id" with the text box and check boxes in the form.